# Can I avoid code duplication when the return type is different?

Tags: c#, code-duplication

I have 2 methods with the exact same logic:

```
Dog RunDog()
{
    // a LOT of businees logic
    return DogMethod(dogParams);
}

Employee RunEmployee()
{
    // the exact same logic from above
    return EmployeeMethod(employeeParams (can be easily converted to/from dogParams));
}
```

Is there a common design pattern to help me avoid the code duplication?

Perhaps something like:

```
T RunT()
{
    // Logic...
    // Invoke DogMethod/EmployeeMethod depending on T and construct the params accodringly
}
```

I chose Dog/Employee to emphasize that there's no easy way to convert between the two.

Comment: So your employees are dogs? ;)

Comment: If it's the exact same logic you could create an additional method and call it in `RunDog()` and `RunEmployee()` to avoid redundancy.

Comment: Well maybe uncouple your business logic from your Run method and see if you can use this to initiate your dog & employee? If you have then 2 utility methods to RunDog & RunEmployee, but your business logic is the same, then you are fine. It would make it a lot easier then if your dog and employee share a base Interface or parent class, cause then you could add it to the generic type as a restriction like `where T: IBaseDataType` or something similar

Comment: @ThiefMaster - No Shmoopy just works them like dogs!!  :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the two methods return different types then they do different things although they use the same business logic internally. So I would extract the commonly used business logic like

```
class Running
{
    public Dog RunDog()
    {
        var dogParams = GetParams();
        return DogMethod(dogParams);
    }

    public Employee RunEmployee()
    {
        var dogParams = GetParams();
        var employeeParams = ConvertParams(dogParams);
        return EmployeeMethod(employeeParams);
    }

    private DogParams GetParams()
    {
          // a LOT of business logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the method/action as the parameter:

```
T RunT<T>(Func<T> function){
    return function()
}
```

More about: https://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/09/24/explaining-what-action-and-func-are/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an issue in your modelling system...

If you have two different classes that share the same behavior (or logic) on one or more element, then what they have in common should be in a base class or expressed through an interface.

Let's say you want to make them run, create an interface IRunner

```
interface IRunner
{
    IRunner runMethod(runnerParam);
}
```

So if both your classes implements this class, you do the logic once :

```
IRunner Run()
{
    //Your logic here
    return myRunner.runMethod(runnerParam);
}
```